# Load a model in a form view and edit it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem with my ajax requests, I can not find the way to receive the model of my controller.
I searched the internet but no way to find the answer that can solve my problem.

What I'm trying to do is display the data contained in "results" in my form (name, first name and politeness).
I then want the user to modify this data and click on the "submit" button to send my POST request.

My methods seem correct (at least the GET), I'm pretty sure my problem comes from the way I use ajax.

Could you tell me about the code to edit?

Thank you in advance!

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMember(int id)
{


    try
    {
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient("https://fms171.hostmy.solutions", "helloJAK", userName, password);
    var toFind = new Models.Members { Zkp_WEB = id };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);
        Console.WriteLine(results);    
        bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(results);
        return View(results);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMember(Models.Members model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient("https://fms171.hostmy.solutions", "helloJAK", userName, password);
        var toCreate = new Models.Members { NameFirst = model.NameFirst, NameLast = model.NameLast, Politeness = model.Politeness };
        var results = await client.CreateAsync(toCreate);


        return Ok(results.Response);
    }
    else return BadRequest();
}
```

**View**

```
@model jak.formulaire.Models.Members


<div id="myForm">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Politeness, "Politeness", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Politeness, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter politeness", @id = "Politeness" } })
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Politeness, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zkp_WEB, "Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zkp_WEB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter id", @id = "idMember" } })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameFirst, "First name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameFirst, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter first name", @id = "NameFirst" } })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameLast, "Last name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameLast, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter last name", @id = "NameLast" } })
    </div>

    <br /><br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEdit">Submit</button>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@section Scripts{


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            GetMember();
            Edit();

        }); 

        function GetMember() {

            //$('#btnEdit').click(function () {
            //    var idMember = $('#idMember').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/" + 2,
                    dataType: "json"


                });
            //});
        }

        function Edit() {

            $('#btnEdit').on('click', function () {
                var idMember = $('#idMember').val();

                myFormdata = {
                    Politeness: Politeness,
                    NameFirst: NameFirst,
                    NameLast: NameLast
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/",
                    data: JSON.stringify(myFormdata),
                    dataType: "json" ,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data === "success") {
                            alert("User successfully modified");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you sholud use url without domain name

> url: "/Members/GetMember/"

now try

Comment: Same result, actually ajax find the good route, but my problem is when ajax has to handle the return of my methods.

Comment: so did you console your return object 
what did it return

Comment: my return value is a IEnumarable<Member> who contain the lastname,firstname,politeness of the good member.

Comment: i think you did missing 'var' when initializing formdata object

Comment: and commit [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on controller

Comment: Hmm, could you provide me an example? i cant reach out how to do it =/

Comment: just remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in your action "GetMember" locate on above action

Comment: and use 
var  myFormdata = {
                    Politeness: Politeness,
                    NameFirst: NameFirst,
                    NameLast: NameLast
                };
when initilize myformdata obj in js

Comment: Okey, the POST is working now! Thanks buddy!
Now i need to make it work for the GET.. i really dont understand why my form is not loaded with my model as it should be when i enter on the page..

Comment: did you debug? is your GetMember() in js  hit action GetMember in controller?

Comment: Yep, it is! It goes until the return View(results) then i receive an error 500. I precise that in my "results" in debug mode i see the model with the member's informations

Comment: And also for the POST, my function GetMember (Model.Members member) always receive an empty member.. i dont get why because when i debug on chrome, the myFormdata is filled normally..

Answer (score 0):

How will the function ever know what NameFirst, NameLast and Politeness are? You are never passing them to the function?

Try removing

```
contentType
```

and

```
dataType
```

from this ajax call.

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/",
                data: JSON.stringify(myFormdata),
                dataType: "json" ,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === "success") {
                        alert("User successfully modified");
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

Passing the model to the controller seems to work fine for me doing that.

A better way to carry out this action would be to do the following:

1) Wrap the form in a Html.BeginForm

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "//form ID" }))
{
     //You form HTML code
}
```

2) Have a function such as this:

```
$(function () {
    $("//form ID").submit(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //Your code to call the controller
        //Just serialize the form like this
        var formData = $("//form ID").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")',
            type:'POST',
            data: formData,
            success:function(result){
                //Whatever
            }
        })
     }
 }
```

Comment: I also receive the model in my controller but NameFirst, nameLast and Politeness are null :(

Comment: @Korpin Take a look at the edit to my answer. Instead of serializing myFormdata, just serealize the form. Also, how will the javascript ever knwo what NameFirst, NameLast and Politeness are. You are never passing them to the function.

Comment: Perfect, it works great now! POST is solved! Any guess for the Get method who dont send info to my form?